# Prompt-toolkit version issue- incompatible with rasa-core and spyder

Tags: spyder, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, prompt-toolkit

I am training a question answering model with rasa-nlu and rasa-core from terminal, wherein it requires the version of prompt-toolkit to be less than version 2.0.0 and when I try to open spyder IDEfrom Anaconda prompt, it is throwing error as it is expecting the prompt-toolkit version to be greater than 2. If I upgrade the version of prompt-toolkit the rasa-core code throws error in terminal. Is there any way to overcome this problem?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) On the Spyder side, the solution is to update to our latest version (3.3.2), which won't show the error you mentioned. That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

This was due to the not maintained dependency for `PyInquirer` in Rasa Core.
The library `PyInquirer` is replaced in the new Rasa Core release `0.13.0` with the library `questionary`. If you already want to have the latest release you can use the latest alpha version, by doing `pip install rasa_core==0.13.0a5`.